# How to convert a pdf of doc file with Watermark in Node.js or angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pdf, watermark

I am new to **Node.js** and **AngularJS**. I have been working on converting my **pdf or doc file with water mark**. I was using **image-watermark** to convert my pdf file with water mark.

This is my coding on **app.js**,

```
var express=require('express');
var mysql=require('mysql');
var path=require('path');
var app=express();
var watermark = require('image-watermark');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
(function() {
    var childProcess = require("child_process");
    var oldSpawn = childProcess.exec;
    function mySpawn() {
        console.log('spawn called');
        console.log(arguments);
        var result = oldSpawn.apply(this, arguments);
        return result;
    }
    childProcess.spawn = mySpawn;
})();
app.get('/fileDoc',function(req,res){
    res.send(watermark.embedWatermark('Err_SigninGoogle (1).png',{'text':'Crisp watermark'}));
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('Server listening on Port 3000');
});
```

After spending long time in fixing this issue i was facing this error in my console on **spawn**.

```
spawn called
{ '0': 'identify',
  '1': [ '-verbose', 'Err_SigninGoogle (1).png' ] }
```

If anybody can help me to fix this issue guide me. Or give some ideas to do this stuff in some other different way.

**Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: Why do you override node's own `spawn()` with `exec()`?

Comment: Though if i do not ovverride with exec I get the same error!!@Samuel Bolduc

Comment: What you provide in your post is not an error message, but only the debug of your two `console.log()`. Do you have an actual error message? If so, add it to the main post

Comment: `spawn called
{ '0': 'identify',
  '1': [ '-verbose', 'angularjs_tutorial1.pdf' ] }
C:\Sample app\node_modules\image-watermark\watermark.js:196
                throw new Error('Image-Watermark::embedWatermark : Unable to process image file
 : ' + err);Error: Image-Watermark::embedWatermark : Unable to process image file : Error: Command failed:

    at C:\Sample app\node_modules\image-watermark\watermark.js:196:11
    at null.callback (C:\Sample app\node_modules\imagemagick\imagemagick.js:168:5)` this is what the error i have faced. @Samual Bolduc